# How to fix TPT script error? 'MSG='[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation' '

Tags: sql-server, odbc, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am using **Teradata Parallel Transport** to select and insert data from tables in a SQL Server to identical tables in a Teradata database. I have done this before successfully but this is the first time I've seen this error when running the script through command line I get this output:

```
TD_LOADER: connecting sessions
TD_LOADER: preparing target table(s)
TD_LOADER: entering DML Phase
TD_LOADER: entering Acquisition Phase
ODBC_READER: sending SELECT request
ODBC_READER: TPT17107: Retrieval error for row: 1
ODBC_READER: TPT17101: Fatal error received from ODBC driver:
STATE=01004, CODE=0,
MSG='[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation'
ODBC_READER: TPT17101: Fatal error received from ODBC driver:
STATE=01004, CODE=0,type here
```

A section of the .out file generated by the script shows:

```
TD_LOADER: connecting sessions
TD_LOADER: preparing target table(s)
TD_LOADER: entering DML Phase
TD_LOADER: entering Acquisition Phase
Job step 'load_the_data' uses the max row size 1024KB.
Job step 'load_the_data' uses the max Using Data Bytes: 1023991.
Job step 'load_the_data' allows data source containing rows that exceed the maximun 
length of 1024KB
Task(APPLY_1[0001]): checkpoint completed, status = Success
Task(SELECT_2[0001]): checkpoint completed, status = Success
ODBC_READER: sending SELECT request
ODBC_READER: TPT17107: Retrieval error for row: 1
ODBC_READER: TPT17101: Fatal error received from ODBC driver:
STATE=01004, CODE=0,
MSG='[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation' 
ODBC_READER: TPT17101: Fatal error received from ODBC driver:
STATE=01004, CODE=0,
```

All of my TPT scripts follow this template:

```
USING CHAR SET ASCII
DEFINE JOB JobName
DESCRIPTION 'Load data from SQL(tablename) to Teradata(tablename)'


(
  DEFINE OPERATOR Database_Commands()
  TYPE DDL
  ATTRIBUTES
  (
    VARCHAR TdpId = @Teradata_Connection,
    VARCHAR UserName = @Teradata_UserId,
    VARCHAR UserPassword = @Teradata_Password,
    VARCHAR Array ErrorList = ['2580'],
    VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'ddllog.txt',
    VARCHAR Tracelevel='None',
    VARCHAR LogSQL = ''
 );
  
  /*Examples*/
  DEFINE SCHEMA SourceTableSchema
  (
     columnname      INTEGER,
     columnname2     VARCHAR(50),
     columnname3     VARCHAR(85),
     columnname4     VARCHAR(15),
     columnname4     BYTEINT    
  );
  
  
  DEFINE SCHEMA TargetTableSchema
  (
     columnname      INTEGER,
     columnname2     VARCHAR(50),
     columnname3     VARCHAR(85),
     columnname4     VARCHAR(15),
     columnname4     BYTEINT     
  );
  

  DEFINE OPERATOR ODBC_READER
  TYPE ODBC
  SCHEMA SourceTableSchema
  ATTRIBUTES
  (
      VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'odbc_log.txt',  
      VARCHAR dsnName = 'SQLDatabaseName',                              
      VARCHAR UserName = @ODBC_UserId,        
      VARCHAR UserPassword = @ODBC_Password,
      VARCHAR TraceLevel = 'None',
      VARCHAR SelectStmt = @SQL 
  );
  
   
  DEFINE OPERATOR TD_LOADER()
  TYPE UPDATE
  SCHEMA TargetTableSchema
  ATTRIBUTES
  (
    VARCHAR TargetTable = @TargetTable,
    VARCHAR LogTable    = @ErrDatabase||'.'||@TargetTable||'_LT', 
    VARCHAR WorkTable   = @WorkDatabase||'.'||@TargetTable||'_WT',
    VARCHAR ErrorTable1 = @ErrDatabase||'.'||@TargetTable||'_ET',
    VARCHAR ErrorTable2 = @ErrDatabase||'.'||@TargetTable||'_UV',
    VARCHAR DateForm = 'IntegerDate',
    VARCHAR TdpId = @Teradata_Connection,
    VARCHAR UserName = @Teradata_UserId,
    VARCHAR UserPassword = @Teradata_Password,
    VARCHAR WorkingDatabase = @TargetDatabase,
    VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'td_loader_log.txt'
  );

STEP RELEASE
  (
     APPLY
           ' release mload '|| @TargetDatabase ||'.'||@TargetTable ||'  ;'
     TO OPERATOR (Database_Commands());
   );


STEP Initialize
  (
     APPLY
           ' delete from '|| @TargetDatabase ||'.'||@TargetTable ||' '||@DeleteScope||' ;'
     TO OPERATOR (Database_Commands());
   );


STEP load_the_data
  (
    APPLY 
         ('INSERT INTO '|| @TargetDatabase ||'.'||@TargetTable||'
                            (   
                           
                             ...columnnames...

                            );'
          )
    TO OPERATOR (TD_LOADER)
       SELECT                      
                                   
              ...columnnames...
    
         FROM OPERATOR (ODBC_READER); 
  );
);
```

I tried checking the table definitions for both the target and the source tables but since the target tables were created using the definitions of the source tables, they are identical so I am not sure what the sizing issue is between them.

Comment: Is the source data single-byte ASCII or is it NVARCHAR?

Comment: Have you tried **not** using the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` driver? Is there some reason you're not using the modern and supported `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` or `ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server`?

Comment: Building on @Fred 's comment, how is the target column defined (latin, unicode?)

Comment: In the tables where I run into this problem, the collation for some source columns are SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, which I believe is typically single-byte ASCII. Though in each of these columns the data type is typically always nvarchar or char. In the corresponding target columns each data type is either varchar or char respectively and they are all defined as 'CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC'

Comment: NCHAR/NVARCHAR columns are UCS-2 / UTF16 - two bytes per character. For tables where all the character columns are NVARCHAR, use UNICODE in the Teradata table and UTF16 in TPT (and either double the lengths or use ADJUST UNICODE option to do that for you).  If you have a mix of VARCHAR and NVARCHAR columns, you need to do a conversion in the SQL Server SELECT. (All the character columns in the TPT SCHEMA will use the same session character set.)

Answer (score 0):

I set the value for `VARCHAR SelectStmt = @SQL` in a separate file. In this file I had to change the select statement from one that selects all, to a statement that explicitly selects each row individually and converts `NVARCHAR` columns into `VARCHAR` columns (as @Fred suggested).

```
CAST(SourceColumnName AS VARCHAR(LengthofTargetColumn)) AS TargetColumnName
```